# Initializing OpenSSL library in C++ / VS2012 crash my app :(

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to use openSSL in a c++ proxy in order to print certificate.

I linked the openSSL library in VS2012, then i did :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#define _LP_MAIN_CPP_
#include "LP_config.h"
#include "LP_log.h"
#include "LP_cache.h"
#include "LP_socket.h"


#define CMD_SIZE        32              // max http COMMAND buf size                
#define URI_SIZE        2048            // max http URI buf size
#define VER_SIZE        32              // max http VERSION buf size
#define START_LINE_SIZE (CMD_SIZE+URI_SIZE+VER_SIZE)    // max size of start line of http protocol
#define HEAD_LINE_SIZE  2048            // max size of one line of header of http protocol
#define C_BUFSIZE       10240           // bufsize of receiving data from client
#define W_BUFSIZE       40960           // bufsize of receiving data from website
#define STKSIZE         ((C_BUFSIZE+W_BUFSIZE+START_LINE_SIZE)*2)   // stack size of every proxy thread
#define QLEN            SOMAXCONN       // maximum connection queue length
#define WSVERS          MAKEWORD(2,0)

#define PROXY_ABOUT     "Lite Proxy, ver. 0.6"

int     DoProxy(SOCKET);

/*----------------------------------------------------------
* main - main entry of concurrent Lite HTTP PROXY server
*----------------------------------------------------------*/
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    struct  sockaddr_in fsin;       // the address of a client
    int     alen;                   // length of client's address
    WSADATA wsadata;
    SOCKET  msock, ssock;           // master and slave server sockets for responding to the requests of clients

    InitLog();
    LogBegin(3);

    InitConfig();

    if (WSAStartup(WSVERS, &wsadata) != 0)
        ErrExit("WSAStartup failed\n");
    if (CreatePassiveSock(msock, service, "tcp", QLEN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        ErrExit("Proxy master listen socket can't be created.\n");

    Log("-> Lite Proxy Server is running on port %s \n", service);
    Log("-> To quit, just close this console window.\n\n");

    InitCache();

    LogEnd();

    while (1) {
        alen = sizeof(fsin);
        ssock = accept(msock, (struct sockaddr *)&fsin, &alen);
        if (ssock == INVALID_SOCKET)
            ErrExit("accept: error number %d\n", GetLastError());
        if (_beginthread((void(*)(void *))DoProxy, STKSIZE, (void *)ssock) < 0)
            ErrExit("_beginthread DoProxy: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    return -1;  //never reach here
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* GetOneLine - Get one line that ends with "\r\n" from HTTP request or reponse
*      input - line: point to the string which will be returned;
*              input: point to the input char array;
*              len: the length of input char array;
*     return - if succeed, return the length of the line and modify input pointer
*              to point to the beginning of the next line
*              otherwise, return -1
*     notice - if return 0, it means getting one bland line which means the end of
*              http request headers
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int
GetOneLine(char * line, char * (&input), int len)
{
    char * p;
    char * q;
    int c = 0;

    if (len < 2)
        return -1;
    p = input;
    q = line;
    while ((c<len) && ((*p != 0xd) || (*(p + 1) != 0xa))) {
        *q++ = *p++;
        c++;
    }
    if ((c + 2)>len)
        return -1;
    *q = 0;
    input = p + 2;
    return c;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* FindEndOfHeaders - Find the end of the headers of http request
*            input - p: point to the char array of http headers
*                    len: the length of char array of http headers
*           return - pointer of the beginning of http request body,
*                    if can't find it, return NULL pointer
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
char *
FindEndOfHeaders(char * p, int len)
{
    int c = 0;

    while (c<len) {
        if ((*p == 0xd) && (*(p + 1) == 0xa) && (*(p + 2) == 0xd) && (*(p + 3) == 0xa))
            break;
        c++;
        p++;
    }
    if ((c + 4) <= len)
        return p + 4;
    else
        return NULL;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* MakeStartLine - Construct one new start line which is prepared to send to website
*         input - dest: point to the char array of new start line;
*                 cmd: point to the string of http commandain
*                 uri: point to the string of http uri
*                 ver: point to the string of http version
*        return - the length of new start line
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int
MakeStartLine(char * dest, char * cmd, char * uri, char * ver)
{
    char * p;

    p = dest;
    while (*cmd)
        *p++ = *cmd++;
    *p++ = ' ';
    while (*uri)
        *p++ = *uri++;
    *p++ = ' ';
    while (*ver)
        *p++ = *ver++;
    *p++ = 0xd;
    *p++ = 0xa;
    return (p - dest);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* SendErrMsg - Constructer one 401 http reponse and send it to the client
*      input - s: the socket to which the messeage will be sent
*              err_str: point to the error string;
*              err_msg: point to the error message string;
*     return - as same as the send()
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
char *msg_http = "HTTP/1.0 %d %s\r\n"
"MIME-version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
"<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>401 Infraction</TITLE></HEAD>"
"<BODY><H1>%d %s</H1><H3>%s</H3><H3>%s</H3><HR><H4>"
PROXY_ABOUT
"</H4><H5>Le temps de delegue: %s</H5>"
"</BODY></HTML>";

int
SendErrMsg(SOCKET s, char * err_str, char * err_msg)
{
    char msg[URI_SIZE + 1024];
    int c;
    time_t ltime;

    time(&ltime);

    c = sprintf(msg, msg_http, 401, "Unauthorized", 401, "Infraction", err_str, err_msg, ctime(&ltime));
    Log("[filter] %s\n", err_msg);
    return send(s, msg, c + 1, 0);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* DoProxy - when get the new connection from client, start this thread to process requests.
*           It will basically follow the sequence like that:
*           get request from client -> analyse the request -> send the request to server
*           -> get the reponse from server -> send the reponse to client
*           -> get next request from client ...
*   input - csock: the socket which is connected with the client;
*  return - 0
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
char connection_close[] = "Connection: close";
char content_length[] = "Content-Length: ";
char content_type[] = "Content-Type: text/html";
char proxy_keep_alive[] = "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive";
char no_cache[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
char last_modified[] = "Last-Modified: ";
char tunnel_ok[] = "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n";

int
DoProxy(SOCKET csock)
{
    char    cbuf[C_BUFSIZE + 1];    // buffer of client
    char    wbuf[W_BUFSIZE + 1];    // buffer of remote site
    char    cmd[CMD_SIZE + 1];  // command string of http request
    char    uri[URI_SIZE + 1];  // URI string of http request
    char    ver[VER_SIZE + 1];  // version string of http request
    char    startline[START_LINE_SIZE + 1]; // startline string of http request or reponse
    char    headline[HEAD_LINE_SIZE + 1];       // header string of http request or reponse
    char    remote[128];        // remote site address string (include port number, if it has)

    int     cc, lcc;                // cc: counter of cbuf[], lcc: last value of cc
    int     wc, lwc;                // wc: counter of wbuf[], lwc: last value of wc
    int     slc, nslc;          // slc: length of startline, nslc: length of new startline created by proxy
    int     req_hc, req_bc, req_rc; // length of header, body and the part not be processed in http request
    int     rep_hc, rep_bc, rep_rc; // length of header, body and the part not be processed in http reponse
    int     uri_len, i;
    SOCKET  wsock;      //wsock: socket for website; csock: socket for client
    fd_set  rfds, afds; //rfds: read file/socket descriptor set; afds: active file/socket descriptor set
    char    * p, *webaddr, *path, *port, *req_rest, *req_body, *rep_body, *rep_begin;
    int     f_has_wsock, f_tunnel, f_web_close, f_type_html, f_another_req;
    int     f_req_incomplete, f_rep_incomplete;
    int     status_code;
    char    * cache_buf;
    int     cache_size, cache_count;
    char    cache_uri[URI_SIZE + 1];
    int     f_save_img;
    int     year;
    struct  linger linger_opt;
    int     tid;

    tid = GetCurrentThreadId();
    LogBegin(1);

    f_has_wsock = 0;
    f_tunnel = 0;
    f_web_close = 0;
    f_req_incomplete = 0;
    f_rep_incomplete = 0;
    f_another_req = 0;
    f_save_img = 0;

    lcc = 0;
    lwc = 0;

    // SSL TEST DEBUT

//  SSL_library_init();

    BIO              *certbio = NULL;
    BIO               *outbio = NULL;
    X509                *cert = NULL;
    X509_NAME       *certname = NULL;
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *ssl;
    int server = 0;
    int ret, j;

    /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
    * These function calls initialize openssl for correct work.  *
    * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
    //OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    /*ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    SSL_load_error_strings();*/


    //SSL TEST FIN


    linger_opt.l_onoff = 1;
    linger_opt.l_linger = 3;    // timeout of closing socket is 3 seconds
    setsockopt(csock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char FAR *)(&linger_opt), sizeof(struct linger));

    FD_ZERO(&afds);
    FD_SET(csock, &afds);   // let select() can detect data from client

    while (1) {
        // select() will be blocked untill there are some data input from client or website
        memcpy(&rfds, &afds, sizeof(rfds));
        if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &rfds, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, (struct timeval *)0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            ErrExit("[tid:%x] select error(%d)\n", tid, GetLastError());

        // proxy works as a tunnel for HTTPS protocol
        if (f_tunnel) {
            if (FD_ISSET(wsock, &rfds)) {   // have data coming from remote site
                if ((wc = recv(wsock, wbuf, W_BUFSIZE, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    Log("\n[tid:%x] recv() from remote site error(%d)\n", tid, GetLastError());
                if (wc <= 0) {              // remote site closed the socket
                    Log("\n[tid:%x] remote site closed the socket in tunnel\n", tid);
                    break;
                }
                if ((cc = send(csock, wbuf, wc, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR) { // copy data: remote site -> client
                    Log("\n[tid:%x] send() to client error(%d)\n", tid, GetLastError());
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (FD_ISSET(csock, &rfds)) {   // have data coming from client
                if ((cc = recv(csock, cbuf, C_BUFSIZE, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    Log("\n[tid:%x] recv() from client error(%d)\n", tid, GetLastError());
                if (cc <= 0) {              // client closed the socket
                    Log("\n[tid:%x] client closed the socket in tunnel\n", tid);
                    break;
                }
                if ((wc = send(wsock, cbuf, cc, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR) { // copy data: client -> remote site
                    Log("\n[tid:%x] send() to remote site error(%d)\n", tid, GetLastError());
                    break;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }

        if (!FD_ISSET(csock, &rfds)) { // check whether the data is from website
            if (recv(wsock, wbuf, W_BUFSIZE, 0) <= 0) { // website want to close the socket
                Log("\n[tid:%x] website closed the socket after sending one reponse\n", tid);
                break;
            }
            else {
                // never reach hear. if it reach, there is something wrong.
                Log("\n[tid:%x] !!!website push some data actively, it is wrong\n", tid);
                break;
            }
        }

        //
        // have data coming from client
        //
    GetRequest:
        if ((cc = recv(csock, cbuf + lcc, C_BUFSIZE - lcc, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            Log("\n[tid:%x] recv from client error when getting http request: %d\n", tid, GetLastError());
        if (cc <= 0) {              // client closed the socket
            Log("\n[tid:%x] client closed the socket\n", tid);
            break;
        }

        if (f_req_incomplete)   // if the last data doesn't have complete request headers, we should merge all data
            cc = cc + lcc;

    AnalyseNextRequest:
        // check the integrity of startline and all headers
        if ((req_body = FindEndOfHeaders(cbuf, cc)) != NULL) {
            //Log("\n[tid:%x] got hearders of request\n",tid);
            f_req_incomplete = 0;
            lcc = 0;
        }
        else if (cc < C_BUFSIZE) {
            Log("\n[tid:%x] can't find End of Hearders of request, need more data\n", tid);
            f_req_incomplete = 1;
            lcc = cc;
            goto GetRequest; // incomplete, should get more data
        }
        else {
            Log("\n[tid:%x] can't find End of Hearders of request, cbuf is full\n", tid);
            break;
        }

        p = cbuf;
        while ((*p < 'A') || (*p > 'Z')) p++;   // to find the first legal letter of start line

        slc = GetOneLine(startline, p, min(cc, START_LINE_SIZE));   // get startline of http request
        if (slc < sizeof("GET http://a.com HTTP/1.x")) {        // can't find start line 
            Log("\n[tid:%x] GetOneLine(StartLine) error %d\n", tid, slc);
            break;
        }

        sscanf(startline, "%s %s %s", cmd, uri, ver);       // split start line 
        Log("\n[tid:%x]HTTP request\n\t[CMD:]\t%s\n\t[URI:]\t%s\n\t[VER:]\t%s\n", tid, cmd, uri, ver);

        if (strcmp(cmd, "CONNECT") == 0) {      // create a tunnel for client. for example, HTTPS 
            webaddr = uri;
            port = strstr(webaddr, ":");        // split server into address and port
            *port++ = 0;
            if (ConnectSock(wsock, webaddr, port, "tcp") == SOCKET_ERROR) // can't create socket for remote site
                break;
            FD_SET(wsock, &afds);           // let select() can detect all data from remote site
            f_tunnel = 1;                                   // set the flag of tunnel
            send(csock, tunnel_ok, sizeof(tunnel_ok) - 1, 0);   // reponse to client for indicating tunnel is OK

            // TEST ICI

            /* Connect the SSL socket */
            /*ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
            sbio = BIO_new_socket(sock, BIO_NOCLOSE);
            SSL_set_bio(ssl, sbio, sbio);

            if (SSL_connect(ssl) <= 0)
                printf("SSL connect error");

            X509 *peer;
            peer = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
            PEM_write_X509(stdout, peer);

            SSL_CTX_free(ctx);*/

            // FIN TEST

            continue;
        }
        else if (filter_post && (strcmp(cmd, "POST") == 0)) {   // if filter_post = 1, we will block POST
            SendErrMsg(csock, cmd, "Cette methode est interdite!");
            break;
        }
        else if (filter_put && (strcmp(cmd, "PUT") == 0)) { // if filter_put = 1, we will block PUT
            SendErrMsg(csock, cmd, "Cette methode est interdite!");
            break;
        }
        else if (open_cache && (strcmp(cmd, "GET") == 0)) { // if open_cache = 1, we will use cache machanism
            uri_len = strlen(uri);
            if ((strcmp(&uri[uri_len - 4], ".jpg") == 0) || (strcmp(&uri[uri_len - 4], ".gif") == 0)) {
                cache_buf = GetFromCache(uri, &cache_size);
                if (cache_buf != NULL) { // if the GET request hit the cache, send the data from cache to client
                    cache_count = send(csock, cache_buf, cache_size, 0);
                    Log("  [cache]sended bytes: %i\n", cache_count);
                    if (cache_count < 0)
                        Log("  [cache]can't send, error: %d\n", GetLastError());
                    free(cache_buf);
                    break;
                }
                else { // if we can't find it in cache, we will prepare to save the reponse from server into cache
                    f_save_img = 1;
                    strcpy(cache_uri, uri);
                }
            }
        }

        if (strncmp(uri, "http://", 7)) {
            SendErrMsg(csock, uri, "This protocol has not been implemented. Sorry!");
            break;  // can't find correct URI
        }

        if (filter_uri) {   // if filter_uri = 1, we will block some websites which are defined in LitProxy.INI file 
            for (i = 0;i<uri_filter_max;i++) {
                uri_len = strlen(uri_filter[i]);
                if (strncmp(uri, uri_filter[i], uri_len) == 0)
                    break;
            }
            if (i<uri_filter_max) {
                SendErrMsg(csock, uri, "Ce site est blocque!");
                break;
            }
        }

        cbuf[cc] = 0;                           // truncate cbuf as a C String

                                                // build connection with website, for example: uri point to "http://www.website.com:3128/index.html
        webaddr = uri + 7;
        path = strstr(webaddr, "/");    // split website address and path
        *path++ = 0;                // now webaddr point to "www.website.com:3128", path point to "index.html"

        if ((f_has_wsock) && strcmp(remote, webaddr)) {
            // sometimes client send http request to another website by using one persistent connection 
            Log("Address of remote site has been changed!\n");
            FD_CLR(wsock, &afds);
            closesocket(wsock);
            f_has_wsock = 0;
        }

        if (!f_has_wsock) {         // we need setup one connection with server
            strcpy(remote, webaddr); // keep address of remote site
            if ((port = strstr(webaddr, ":")) == NULL)
                port = "80";        // set default port of http
            else
                *port++ = 0;        // get website port, now webaddr point to "www.website.com", port point to "3128"
            if (ConnectSock(wsock, webaddr, port, "tcp") == SOCKET_ERROR) break;
            setsockopt(wsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char FAR *)(&linger_opt), sizeof(struct linger));
            //Log("wsock = %x\n",wsock);
            FD_SET(wsock, &afds);
            f_has_wsock = 1;
        }

        // construct one new start line with partial URI 
        // because some websites, like news.sina.com.cn, 
        // can't support full URI.
        path--;
        *path = '/';    // now path point to "/index.html"
        nslc = MakeStartLine(startline, cmd, path, ver);

        req_rest = p;   // now p point to the beginning of http headers
        req_rc = cc - (p - cbuf);

        // analyse http request headers
        req_bc = 0;
        Log("\t[HEADERS:]\n");
        while ((req_hc = GetOneLine(headline, p, min(req_rc, HEAD_LINE_SIZE))) > 0) {
            // get http header one by one
            // when GetOneLine return 0, it means all headers have been processed
            Log("\t\t%s\n", headline);
            req_rc = req_rc - req_hc - 2;
            if (strncmp(headline, content_length, sizeof(content_length) - 1) == 0) {
                // find header "Content-Length", it means the length of body after headers
                req_bc = atoi(&headline[sizeof(content_length) - 1]);
                Log("\t\t\tuploading body length = %d\n", req_bc);
            }
        }
        req_rc = req_rc - 2;    // if rep_rc > 0, it means that there is one http body after http headers

                                // send new start line to remote website 
        send(wsock, startline, nslc, 0);
        // send headers to remote website
        send(wsock, req_rest, req_body - req_rest, 0);

        f_another_req = 0;
        if (req_bc) {                   // client POST or PUT some data
            if (req_bc > req_rc) {      // all the rest is a part of http request body
                req_bc = req_bc - req_rc;
                send(wsock, req_body, req_rc, 0);
                Log("\t\t\tremaining uploading body length = %d\n", req_bc);
                while (req_bc > 0) {
                    if ((cc = recv(csock, cbuf, C_BUFSIZE, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                        Log("\n[tid:%x] recv from client error when getting data : %d\n", tid, GetLastError());
                    if (cc <= 0) {              // client closed the socket
                        Log("\n[tid:%x] client closed the socket after sending data\n", tid);
                        goto ExitDoProxy;
                    }
                    req_bc -= cc;
                    if (req_bc < 0) {
                        Log("\n[tid:%x] upload count error, req_bc = %d\n", tid, req_bc);
                        goto ExitDoProxy;
                    }
                    Log("\t\t\tremaining uploading body length = %d\n", req_bc);
                    send(wsock, cbuf, cc, 0);
                }
            }
            else {
                send(wsock, req_body, req_bc, 0);
                req_rc = req_rc - req_bc;
                if (req_rc > 0) {   // if req_rc > 0, it means that there is another request after this body
                    memmove(cbuf, req_body + req_bc, req_rc);
                    cc = req_rc;
                    f_another_req = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        //
        // wait the reponse of website
        //
    GetReponse:
        if ((wc = recv(wsock, wbuf + lwc, W_BUFSIZE - lwc, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            Log("\n[tid:%x] recv from website error: %d\n", tid, GetLastError());
        if (wc <= 0) {              // website closed the socket
            Log("\n[tid:%x] website closed the socket\n", tid);
            break;
        }

        if (f_rep_incomplete)   // if the last data doesn't have complete reponse headers, we should merge all data
            wc = wc + lwc;

        if ((rep_body = FindEndOfHeaders(wbuf, wc)) != NULL) {
            //Log("\n[tid:%x] got hearders of reponse\n",tid);
            f_rep_incomplete = 0;
            lwc = 0;
        }
        else if (wc < W_BUFSIZE) {
            Log("\n[tid:%x] can't find End of Hearders of reponse, need more data\n", tid);
            f_rep_incomplete = 1;
            lwc = wc;
            goto GetReponse;
        }
        else {
            Log("\n[tid:%x] can't find End of Hearders of reponse, wbuf is full\n", tid);
            break;
        }

        p = wbuf;
        while (*p != 'H') p++;  // to find the first legal letter of the first reponse line
        rep_begin = p;

        rep_rc = wc - (p - wbuf);

        // analyse reponse headers
        f_type_html = 0;
        rep_bc = 0;
        Log("\n[tid:%x]HTTP reponse\n", tid);
        rep_hc = GetOneLine(startline, p, 64);
        Log("\t\t%s\n", startline);
        rep_rc = rep_rc - rep_hc - 2;
        startline[12] = 0;
        status_code = atoi(&startline[9]);
        while ((rep_hc = GetOneLine(headline, p, min(rep_rc, HEAD_LINE_SIZE))) > 0) {
            Log("\t\t%s\n", headline);
            rep_rc = rep_rc - rep_hc - 2;
            if (strncmp(headline, connection_close, sizeof(connection_close) - 1) == 0) {
                f_web_close = 1; // website will close the socket
            }
            else if (strncmp(headline, content_type, sizeof(content_type) - 1) == 0) {
                f_type_html = 1; // after headers, there will be one html file
            }
            else if (strncmp(headline, content_length, sizeof(content_length) - 1) == 0) {
                // find header "Content-Length", it means the length of body after headers
                rep_bc = atoi(&headline[sizeof(content_length) - 1]);
                Log("\t\t\tbody length = %d\n", rep_bc);
            }
            else if (filter_last_mod && strncmp(headline, last_modified, sizeof(last_modified) - 1) == 0) {
                // if filter_last_mod, we will block the file which is old than the value of "year"
                sscanf(&headline[27], "%d ", &year);
                if (year < last_mod_year) {
                    SendErrMsg(csock, headline, "Ce document est trop vieux!");
                    goto ExitDoProxy;
                }
            }
        }
        rep_rc = rep_rc - 2;            // all headers have been processed

                                        // send headers to client
        send(csock, rep_begin, rep_body - rep_begin, 0);

        cache_buf = NULL;

        if (!f_web_close && f_type_html && (status_code == 200))
            // some websites don't indicate the content-length of html file, but it will close the socket after sending data
            f_web_close = 1;
        if ((status_code != 200))
            rep_bc = 0; // the "Content-Length" has nothing to do with these status codes except code 200 
        else if (f_save_img && rep_bc) {
            // we need to save the reponse to cache, so we allocate the room for the cache buffer
            cache_count = rep_body - rep_begin;
            cache_size = cache_count + rep_bc;
            cache_buf = (char *)malloc(cache_size);
            if (cache_buf != NULL) {
                memcpy(cache_buf, rep_begin, cache_count);
            }
        }

        if (f_web_close || rep_bc) {
            // in this case, remote site has responsibility for closing socket after sending data
            if (rep_rc > 0)
                send(csock, rep_body, rep_rc, 0);
            if (rep_bc > 0) {
                rep_bc -= rep_rc;
                Log("\n[tid:%x]\t\tremaining downloading body length = %d\n", tid, rep_bc);
                if (cache_buf != NULL) {  //save data to cache buffer
                    memcpy(&cache_buf[cache_count], rep_body, rep_rc);
                    cache_count += rep_rc;
                }
                if (rep_bc <= 0) {
                    if (cache_buf != NULL) { // save cache buffer to cache file
                        PutIntoCache(cache_uri, cache_buf, cache_size);
                        free(cache_buf);
                    }
                    goto ExitDoProxy;
                }
            }
            while (1) {
                if ((wc = recv(wsock, wbuf, W_BUFSIZE, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    Log("\n[tid:%x] recv from website error: %d\n", tid, GetLastError());
                if (wc <= 0) {              // website closed the socket
                    Log("\n[tid:%x] website closed the socket after sending data\n", tid);
                    goto ExitDoProxy;
                }
                send(csock, wbuf, wc, 0);
                if (cache_buf != NULL) {  // save data to cache buffer
                    memcpy(&cache_buf[cache_count], wbuf, wc);
                    cache_count += wc;
                }
                if (rep_bc > 0) {
                    rep_bc -= wc;
                    Log("\n[tid:%x]\t\tremaining downloading body length = %d\n", tid, rep_bc);
                    if (rep_bc <= 0) {
                        if (cache_buf != NULL) { //save cache buffer to cache file
                            PutIntoCache(cache_uri, cache_buf, cache_size);
                            free(cache_buf);
                        }
                        goto ExitDoProxy;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (f_another_req) {    // in the request buffer, there is another request to process
            f_another_req = 0;
            f_save_img = 0;
            goto AnalyseNextRequest;
        }
    }

ExitDoProxy:

    // close the sockets gracefully and will end the current thread
    if (f_has_wsock) {
        shutdown(wsock, SD_SEND);
        closesocket(wsock);
    }
    shutdown(csock, SD_SEND);
    closesocket(csock);

    InsertTimeTag(2);
    LogEnd();
    return 0;
}
```

When i run the apps in X86 :

```
"Failed to initialize application (0xc0000007).
```

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm surprised that compiles; Those belong in a function somewhere. Are you saying building, linking, and running [something like this](http://pastebin.com/MC2p5r56) fails ?

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy/paste. I missed my main().

Comment: Are you sure provided example fails? The only strange thing I see here is the usage of `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms`, it's [deprecated](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms.html) from OpenSSL 1.1.0. Probably you should post more code.

Comment: @Nikita, i just updated my code :)

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni If you run your program in Debug at what line of code it will crash?

Comment: @Nikita It crash....before the first ligne in the Main(). So unable to break :\

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem doesn't relate to OpenSSL library.

According to [this](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CIYBEBYwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F9%2F5%2FE%2F95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C%2F%5BMS-ERREF%5D.pdf&ei=17GoT53mCK_R4QSGm6WRCQ&usg=AFQjCNHu2-WVJpA7ViG5e-GAne_gCH9Rzw&sig2=f1N9anRoFy8qDuth62oK7g) document, error code `0xc0000007` means `STATUS_INVALID_WORKSTATION`:

> The user account is restricted so that it cannot be used to log on from the source workstation.

Check access permissions of user you use to run your program. Try to run your program with elevated permissions.

Comment: Sorry guys, i made a terrible error ! The error code is 0xc0000007b ! And it's due my programm use a 64bits dll instead the 32bit dll ! Sorry !

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni Oh, so it's a simple problem, error STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT (0xc0000007b) is more frequent and it's easy to fix.

Comment: I use Dependency walker and the two dll used by OpenSSL are the 64bits dll instead of the 32bits dll. If i paste the two 32bits dll in the build folder, all is ok but it's not smart...how telling visual studio to use the right 32bits dll ?

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni You can use `$(PlatformName)` macros in your post-build event to copy proper OpenSSL dlls. E.g. `copy "$(SolutionDir)OpenSSL\$(PlatformName)\ssleay32.dll" "$(TargetDir)"`